# Data Cleaning Badly Designed JSON Data -- Need advice on best strategy

Tags: json, mongodb, text, jq, data-cleaning

I have over 1,000 JSON files representing game elements. This is a typical example:

```
{
    "name": "Reeve Hunter",
    "edition": 3,
    "revision": "2021 v1",
    "keywords": [
        "Circle",
        "Wolf Sworn",
        "Reeve of Orboros",
        "Solo"
    ],
    "point cost": 4,
    "field allowance": 2,
    "models": [
        {
            "Hunter": {
                "spd": 6,
                "str": 6,
                "mat": 6,
                "rat": 7,
                "def": 13,
                "arm": 13,
                "cmd": 7,
                "boxes": 5,
                "advantages": [
                    "Advance Deploy",
                    "Assault",
                    "Pathfinder"
                ],
                "base size": 30,
                "attacks": [
                    {
                        "Double Crossbow": {
                            "type": "ranged",
                            "rng": 12,
                            "rof": 2,
                            "pow": 10
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Battle Blade": {
                            "type": "melee",
                            "rng": 0.5,
                            "pow": 3,
                            "p+s": 9
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Cleft Sword": {
                            "type": "melee",
                            "rng": 1,
                            "pow": 5,
                            "p+s": 11,
                            "weapon qualities": ["Weapon Master"],
                            "abilities": ["Powerful Charge"]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "abilities": [
                    "Hunter",
                    "Leadership [Reeves of Orboros]",
                    "Quickwork",
                    "Sprint"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

While the above is valid JSON, once I got all the JSON files into a MongoDB database I realized I couldn't analyze my data properly because every sub-document in the `models` and `attacks` arrays had a unique name as the key.

I want to transform each JSON document like this:

```
{
  "name": "Reeve Hunter",
  "edition": 3,
  "revision": "2021 v1",
  "keywords": [
    "Circle",
    "Wolf Sworn",
    "Reeve of Orboros",
    "Solo"
  ],
  "point cost": 4,
  "field allowance": 2,
  "models": [
    {
      "model name": "Hunter",
      "spd": 6,
      "str": 6,
      "mat": 6,
      "rat": 7,
      "def": 13,
      "arm": 13,
      "cmd": 7,
      "boxes": 5,
      "advantages": [
        "Advance Deploy",
        "Assault",
        "Pathfinder"
      ],
      "base size": 30,
      "attacks": [
        {
          "attack name": "Double Crossbow",
          "type": "ranged",
          "rng": 12,
          "rof": 2,
          "pow": 10
        },
        {
          "attack name": "Battle Blade",
          "type": "melee",
          "rng": 0.5,
          "pow": 3,
          "p+s": 9
        },
        {
          "attack name": "Cleft Sword",
          "type": "melee",
          "rng": 1,
          "pow": 5,
          "p+s": 11,
          "weapon qualities": [
            "Weapon Master"
          ],
          "abilities": [
            "Powerful Charge"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "abilities": [
        "Hunter",
        "Leadership [Reeves of Orboros]",
        "Quickwork",
        "Sprint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm an old hat at using `awk` and `sed` for cleaning up text, but this transformation is complex and features enough "gotchas" that I feel like I need a different strategy.

I've been using the wonderful tool `jq` to manipulate and query JSON files, and I feel like there has to be a way to leverage its power to do what I need.

Does anyone have any advice on the best strategy to write a script that can transform all of my data into the cleaner format I require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` to decompose the nested objects into `.key` and `.value`, then rearrange and update using `|=`:

```bash
<file.json jq '.models |= map(to_entries[] | {"model name": .key} + .value)
  | .models[].attacks |= map(to_entries[] | {"attack name": .key} + .value)'
```

```json
{
  "name": "Reeve Hunter",
  "edition": 3,
  "revision": "2021 v1",
  "keywords": [
    "Circle",
    "Wolf Sworn",
    "Reeve of Orboros",
    "Solo"
  ],
  "point cost": 4,
  "field allowance": 2,
  "models": [
    {
      "model name": "Hunter",
      "spd": 6,
      "str": 6,
      "mat": 6,
      "rat": 7,
      "def": 13,
      "arm": 13,
      "cmd": 7,
      "boxes": 5,
      "advantages": [
        "Advance Deploy",
        "Assault",
        "Pathfinder"
      ],
      "base size": 30,
      "attacks": [
        {
          "attack name": "Double Crossbow",
          "type": "ranged",
          "rng": 12,
          "rof": 2,
          "pow": 10
        },
        {
          "attack name": "Battle Blade",
          "type": "melee",
          "rng": 0.5,
          "pow": 3,
          "p+s": 9
        },
        {
          "attack name": "Cleft Sword",
          "type": "melee",
          "rng": 1,
          "pow": 5,
          "p+s": 11,
          "weapon qualities": [
            "Weapon Master"
          ],
          "abilities": [
            "Powerful Charge"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "abilities": [
        "Hunter",
        "Leadership [Reeves of Orboros]",
        "Quickwork",
        "Sprint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pmtNzu1sYFQ)

Comment: Absolutely incredible, this works flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If you have these JSON as files, then `jq` would be one of the best tools, I assume. However, if you have stored them in a MongoDB, then I would propose this update:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            models: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$models",
                  in: {
                     $let: {
                        vars: { model: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } },
                        in: {
                           $mergeObjects: [
                              { "model name": { $first: "$$model.k" } },
                              { $first: "$$model.v" }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         $set: {
            models: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$models",
                  as: "model",
                  in: {
                     $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$model",
                        {
                           attacks: {
                              $map: {
                                 input: "$$model.attacks",
                                 in: {
                                    $let: {
                                       vars: { attack: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } },
                                       in: {
                                          $mergeObjects: [
                                             { "attack name": { $first: "$$attack.k" } },
                                             { $first: "$$attack.v" }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be a way to do it in Mongo, and I very much appreciate you showing me how.